# How to block (or unblock) the ASP.NET error logger Elmah?

Tags: asp.net, elmah, ashx, axd

Some one configured my server in a way that intentionally or inadvertently blocks ELMAH.  I wish I know what that was.  My current server admin can't figure out what's blocking it either.

Clues have so far

- Error message is **"This type of page is not served...it has been explicitly forbidden"**
- Ordinary .ashx handlers work just fine. (HelloWorld.ashx works)
- I'm running in Full Trust.
- I'm on Win 2000, IIS 5
- Machine config doesn't have any references to ELMAH (neither does my web.config)
- The ELMAH_Error table exists, but has no entries.
- My application with ELMAH works fine on my machine (i.e. shows the error log).
- I updated the Handler section to change the name to Elmha.ashx, instead of elmah.axd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening on server I didn't have access to the windows application error log. After getting that, it was obvious that elmah and blowery were not playing well together (headers already sent errors).